# How to dynamic change second select afert change the first

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic

i would like to create dynamic car auto search, and change second select "id=themodel" after change the first "id=thecar". The variables m1,m2,m3 are created dynamicaly by php.

Problem is in this line "$('#themodel').html(themodelID);", and i don`t know how to resolve it, because alert return correct value, and if i replace "themodelID" to (for example) "m1" - it works...

html structure like this

```
 <div class="styled-select">    
                <select id="thecar">
                    <option class="first">- Marka -</option>
                    <option value="1">Audi</option>
                    <option value="2">BMW</option>
                    <option value="3">Fiat</option>
                    <option value="4">Ford</option>
                    <option value="5">Honda</option>
                    <option value="6">Kia</option>
                    <option value="7">Mercedes-Benz</option>
                    <option value="8">Mazda</option>
                    <option value="9">Opel</option>
                    <option value="10">Volkswagen</option>                       
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="styled-select">     
                <select id="themodel">
                    <option class="first">- Model -</option>                     
                </select>
            </div>
```

, here is jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var m1 = '<option value="11">A1</option><option value="12">A2</option><option value="13">A3</option><option value="14">A4</option>';
        var m2 = '<option value="21">318</option><option value="22">320</option><option value="23">525</option><option value="24">530</option>';
        var m3 = '<option value="31">Bravo</option><option value="32">Brava</option><option value="33">Siena</option><option value="34">Ducato</option>';

        $('#thecar').change(function(){     
            var thecarID = $('#thecar').val();              
            var themodelID =  ('m' + thecarID);
            $('#themodel').html(themodelID);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a variable name dynamically. The simplest would be to use an object to store all the options and use `[]` notation to access them

```
 var options = {
     m1: '<option value="11">....',
     m2: '<option value="21">...',
     m3: '<option value="31">...'    
 };

 $('#thecar').change(function(){     
        var thecarID = $('#thecar').val();              
        var themodelID =  ('m' + thecarID);
        $('#themodel').html(options[themodelID]);
    });
```